# Facebook Subscribe Call Back

Tags: ajax, facebook, call, back, subscribe

Facebook subscribe didn't call back. How callback successful?

```
<script> window.fbAsyncInit = function() { 
 FB.init({status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});  var user= "<?
 echo $data->id;?>"; 
 document.getElementById("Hint").style.display='block'; 
 FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "fbareceive.php",
         data: "data="+response + "---" + user,        
         cache: false
     });
 (function() {  var e = document.createElement('script');  e.type =
 'text/javascript';  e.src = document.location.protocol +
 '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';  e.async = true; 
 document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);  }());

 </script>
```

Comment: I do not understand what you need. You need to explain more. Write what you need in your language. Use small, simple sentences. Use this website to translate to English. http://babelfish.yahoo.com/ Then copy the result here.

Answer (score 0):

$.ajax() is a jQuery function. Please read the relevant documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Briefly:

```
$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "fbareceive.php",
         data: "data="+response + "---" + user,        
         cache: false,
         success: function(){
                alert('Success');
            }
        });
```